# 500 Internal Server Error in ASP.NET MVC Bundles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await, bundle

I do bundle my JavaScript files with ASP.NET MVC Bundling. When I inspect and check **Network** Tab in my browser, I see `500 Internal Server Error` when my bundle wants to load.
response:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

I understand that this error happened in my `GenerateIdentityAsync` method.
I use ASP.NET Identity 2.0 so I use it from `OnValidateIdentity` in Owin Startup class:

**ApplicationManager.cs**

```
public class ApplicationManager : IApplicationManager
{
   // more code
   public Func<CookieValidateIdentityContext, Task> OnValidateIdentity()
   {
      return SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<AppUserManager, User, Guid>
      (TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), GenerateIdentityAsync, identity => Guid.Parse(identity.GetUserId()));
   }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateIdentityAsync(AppUserManager manager, User user)
    {
      var identity =
        await  CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie).ConfigureAwait(true);
     identity.AddEnumClaim("lastSeenMode", user.LastSeenMode);
     identity.AddClaim(new Claim("emailAddress", user.Email));
     identity.AddClaim(new Claim("displayName", user.DisplayName));
     identity.AddClaim(new Claim("lastseen", user.LastSeen.ToString()));
     return identity;
   }
}
```

**startup.cs**

```
  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
  {
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = SmObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<IAppUserManager>().OnValidateIdentity(),
        }
  });
```

**Stack**

```
[NotSupportedException: A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use &#39;await&#39; to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.]
System.Data.Entity.Internal.ThrowingMonitor.EnsureNotEntered() +4906656
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.FindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object[] keyValues) +73
System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.FindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object[] keyValues) +35
System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.FindAsync(Object[] keyValues) +26
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.EntityStore`1.GetByIdAsync(Object id) +49
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.&lt;GetUserAggregateAsync&gt;d__6c.MoveNext() +201
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.&lt;GetSecurityStampAsync&gt;d__42.MoveNext() +302
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.&lt;CreateAsync&gt;d__0.MoveNext() +860
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() +28
App.ServiceLayer.UserService.&lt;GenerateIdentityAsync&gt;d__16.MoveNext() in C:\Repository\Barnamenevis.ir\App.ServiceLayer\UserService\AppUserManager.cs:127
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.&lt;&lt;OnValidateIdentity&gt;b__1&gt;d__4.MoveNext() +1581
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) +25
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.&lt;AuthenticateCoreAsync&gt;d__2.MoveNext() +2153
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.&lt;BaseInitializeAsync&gt;d__0.MoveNext() +571
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.&lt;Invoke&gt;d__0.MoveNext() +255
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.&lt;Invoke&gt;d__0.MoveNext() +404
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.&lt;Invoke&gt;d__0.MoveNext() +404
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.&lt;Invoke&gt;d__0.MoveNext() +404
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.&lt;Invoke&gt;d__0.MoveNext() +404
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.&lt;RunApp&gt;d__5.MoveNext() +182
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.&lt;DoFinalWork&gt;d__2.MoveNext() +180
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +69
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar) +64
System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +380
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +155
```

also i test `ConfigureAwait(true)` and `ConfigureAwait(false)` and without `ConfigureAwait` but donot solved this issue.

**Update**:
Also, when I use [EF Profiler](https://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof), it says **Using A Single Object Context In Multiple Threads Is Likely A Bug.**

this alert exist just for same table:

```
[Admin].[UserClaims]
[Admin].[UserLogin]
[Admin].[Roles]
[Admin].[UserRoles]
[Admin].[Users]
```

How can I solve this issue?

More Code in [Gist](https://gist.github.com/SoheilAlizade/47d3da285508dac291558f7ab1962488)

Comment: You somewhere started two async requests to database at same time. Check where you missed using await.

Comment: I don't miss use `await`.

Comment: Can you add post exception call stack to question?

Comment: @vitaliysmolyakov question updated.

Comment: Are you sharing the DbContext across multiple requests?

Comment: @paulomorgado yes,I implement uow pattern.

Comment: How you create IdentityDbContext? It must be created new per request. If you really share one IdentityDbContext instance by multiple requests then this is source of problem - several requests can access DB at same time using one context.

Comment: i create gist please  check [this](https://gist.github.com/SoheilAlizade/47d3da285508dac291558f7ab1962488)

Comment: Also, when I use EF Profiler, it says **Using A Single Object Context In Multiple Threads Is Likely A Bug**

Comment: Looks like another confirmation that the context is being shared.

Comment: @paulomorgado how can I solve this?

Comment: Don't share the context.

Comment: @paulomorgado but, I need uow pattern.

Comment: You are definitely using the same database context across different request. Nothing to do with ASP.NET Bundles.

Comment: I know that **Nothing to do with ASP.NET Bundles**, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I not use StructureMap by myself, but i found that for MVC the best way to use StructureMap with MVC is to install [StructureMap.MVC5.Update](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StructureMap.MVC5.Update/) package (that's for latest StructureMap version).
Check small [intro](https://github.com/webadvanced/Structuremap.MVC5) how to use it. Or [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/structuremap-ioc-with-asp-net-mvc-5/) article.

Move all your existing registration code to DefaultRegistry.cs installed by package. And now don't use `HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()` for services registration.